# How to deal with gender-ambiguous questions?

Tags: discussion, etiquette, wording

Since the English language does not have well-established rules about using gender-neutral pronouns, I always feel uncomfortable when I answer questions where the child's gender is unclear.

Is this OK to refer to a child as "he" in an answer, if the question is ambiguous about that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Historically, *"he"* was generally used in the absence of a gender-neutral pronoun. But in a time of increasing political correctness, *he* can come across as presumptuous. The pronoun *"it"* is genderless, but using *it* to refer to people would likely be considered offensive. "One" is also used, but in conversational English, it sounds a bit silted and formal.

If you cannot reword the response to avoid playing the pronoun game, **use the word "they".**

From [English Language & Usage: Gender neutral pronoun:](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/48/gender-neutral-pronoun)

> Singular they enjoys a long history of usage in English and can be used here: "Each student should save their questions until the end.". However "singular they" also enjoys a long history of criticism. If you are anxious about being criticized (for what is in fact a perfectly grammatical construction) you are advised to reword to avoid having to use a gender neutral singular third-person pronoun.

Answer (score 6):

I often relate my answer to my own son and then it's easy to phrase it so that I can use his gender. Problem solved :-)

Answer (score 4):

It's 100% okay by me, but *some* people would be deeply offended.

I've been using he/she and them in such questions.  Neither sounds great, but it avoids the politically correct crowd throwing a fit.  (Though I'm with you, if the gender is unknown, just picking one at random should be fine.)

Comment: It's sad that some people get offended so easily. It's not like I'm looking at a pink-dressed toddler in a stroller and saying *he*...